# Gradle: How to perform all integration test cases(UI test) under a specific folder in a module

Tags: android, kotlin, jenkins, continuous-integration

Android official site says: Run specific test methods or classes [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#run-specific-test-methods-classes)

`./gradlew testVariantNameUnitTest --tests '*.sampleTestMethod'`

But it is for Unit test, could we do the same for Integration test(UI Test) with gradle. I want to perform all test cases under integration test(dirA) on CI (Jenkins) and generate the test report, its structure is as below. Is it possible to achieve that? Any hint or help would be highly appreciate.

```
moduleA
  - test(dir)
    - integrationtest(dirA)
      - testFileA
      - testFileAA
    - systemtest(dirB)
      - testFileB
      - testFileBB
```

Comment: Specify the test names in the same way, but call the integration test Gradle task instead of the unit test Gradle task.

Comment: @Jorn it got `Unknown command-line option '--tests'.`, our project is having multiple modules, is there something I need to change in this command?